# Pass data from activity to view pager fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

Sorry for broken english.

I created tab layout using retrofit, and there is no problem with tabs name or title.
But when i tried to passing data id to the fragment, there's a problem.

In My Activity :

```
     public void onResponse(Response<CategoryResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
            FragmentKonten deskripsi;
            if(response.body().getStatus().equals("ok"))
            {
                CategoryResponse produkListResponse = response.body();
                for (Category category : produkListResponse.getListProduk())
                {
                    bundle.putInt("category",category.getId());

                    deskripsi=new FragmentKonten();
                    deskripsi.setArguments(bundle);

                    adapter.addFragment(deskripsi,category.getTitle());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            else{
                pesan(getActivity());
            }
        }
```

In my fragment :

```
 bundle = this.getArguments();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("category")),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

the results that i want are :

**Category Title and ID :**

```
Diet Sehat = 3

Khas Indonesia = 4

Resep Kue = 7

Resep Macanegara = 9

etc
```

**But the actual results are :**

```
Diet Sehat = 9

Khas Indonesia = 9

Resep Kue = 9

Resep Macanegara = 9

etc
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your API response to check whether you are  getting the right data?

Comment: @ZayidMohammed yes it is. there's no problem with the API

Comment: What you are doing exactly inside the for each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
for (Category category : produkListResponse.getListProduk())
                {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); //I guess you're missing this
                    bundle.putInt("category",category.getId());

                    deskripsi=new FragmentKonten();
                    deskripsi.setArguments(bundle);

                    adapter.addFragment(deskripsi,category.getTitle());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

Comment: or you have it global, so it's always sit to the last value (9), define it inside the loop